# Copy a line to a DB sheet based on a calculated trigger

Tags: excel, vba

After trying a few different approaches I am stuck.  Basically I have a table where a line is completed every 30 mins or so. The User will enter 3 numbers in a row, the next 3 rows are calculated.  I would like to use one of the calculated rows as a trigger to copy the entire row to a DB sheet (sheet2).  And repeat when the next line is added and so on.  I can only seem to get the 1st line to copy across every time.

The sheet is used as a hardcopy batch record so I have shied away from building a FORM.  I started with the following, which worked for line 1 (also calling a recorded macro to copy in some header data)

```
`Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 If IsNumeric(Range("$h$9")) Then
  If Range("$h$9").Value >= 1 Then
      Application.Run "Macro1"
    End If
End If
End Sub  `
```

Macro1 just copying some of the header form data (date/time,machine info etc that is only entered once for the sheet & the row described above).

I hope this is clear, any questions please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO

Try using a loop like below? Change the upper limit of `i` as you want, and maybe use some form of row counter like `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 9000
If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 8)) Then
    If Cells(i, 8).Value >= 1 Then
       Application.Run "Macro1"
    End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```